# Mobile Vs. Desktop Row Display

Tags: responsive-design, responsive-images

I'm seeking kind help in solving this responsive display issue. I'm able to hide\display the desired image for the device However, I can not hide the row.. So, this places an empty row which displays a large white gap where the hidden image is.  The website is https://restoresell.com/

How can I hide the ROW and the IMAGE so there is NO gap of blank row in display?
NOTE: in the Desktop row version I use a 1900x500 Image and in Mobile row I use a 800x800 image.
Tool used is WBakery Builder

Website: https://restoresell.com/
Problem Location: Home Page First row(s) under the navigation. Top of body content area

HTML code sample:

```
<div data-vc-full-width="true" data-vc-full-width-init="true" data-vc-stretch-content="true" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid gradient-container-1 vc_custom_1634656822945 vc_row-has-fill vc_row-no-padding vc_row-o-full-height vc_row-o-columns-middle vc_row-o-content-middle vc_row-flex" style="position: relative; left: -66px; box-sizing: border-box; width: 1332px; min-height: 77.82vh;"><div class="gradient-column-1 wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12 vc_hidden-lg vc_hidden-md"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_center  vc_custom_1634656121177">
    
    <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
        <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img data-lazyloaded="1" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAMPDwwAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" width="800" height="800" data-src="https://restoresell.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Restoration-Brokers-of-America-Restoration-Business-Consulting-Brokrage-Team.jpg" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-full" alt="Restoration Brokers of America - Restoration Business Consulting &amp; Brokerage Team" loading="lazy" data-srcset="https://restoresell.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Restoration-Brokers-of-America-Restoration-Business-Consulting-Brokrage-Team.jpg 800w, https://restoresell.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Restoration-Brokers-of-America-Restoration-Business-Consulting-Brokrage-Team-300x300.jpg 300w, https://restoresell.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Restoration-Brokers-of-America-Restoration-Business-Consulting-Brokrage-Team-150x150.jpg 150w, https://restoresell.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Restoration-Brokers-of-America-Restoration-Business-Consulting-Brokrage-Team-768x768.jpg 768w" data-sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px"><noscript><img width="800" height="800" src="https://restoresell.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Restoration-Brokers-of-America-Restoration-Business-Consulting-Brokrage-Team.jpg" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-full" alt="Restoration Brokers of America - Restoration Business Consulting &amp; Brokerage Team" loading="lazy" srcset="https://restoresell.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Restoration-Brokers-of-America-Restoration-Business-Consulting-Brokrage-Team.jpg 800w, https://restoresell.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Restoration-Brokers-of-America-Restoration-Business-Consulting-Brokrage-Team-300x300.jpg 300w, https://restoresell.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Restoration-Brokers-of-America-Restoration-Business-Consulting-Brokrage-Team-150x150.jpg 150w, https://restoresell.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Restoration-Brokers-of-America-Restoration-Business-Consulting-Brokrage-Team-768x768.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px" /></noscript></div>
    </figure>
</div>
</div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Questions here are expected to be self-contained; that is, including your code (as a [mre]) along with an explanation of where you're getting stuck. Including a link to your site is not helpful - it will change/break over time and nuke value for future visitors to this question, and right now it looks like thinly-veiled spam. Please update your question to conform to our guidelines on [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a class and insert it to row settings "extra class".  Than insert css in page custom css.